Replace <WOOT> Occurances within Cape v2 Sandbox Script
Currently trying to install Cape v2 on an Azure VM that I have set up. I am following instructions on the website here.
The instructions say:
"BEFORE executing the script, you should replace the  occurrences withing the script itself with real hardware patterns. You can use acpidump in Linux and acpiextract in Windows to obtain such patterns, as stated in the script itself."
I was able to get to the point where I did an acpidump and extracted info from the DSDT file. However, I am not able to find the specific characters in order to replace the  occurances. The occurances from the script are these:
# what to use as a replacement for QEMU in the tablet info
PEN_REPLACER='<WOOT>'

# what to use as a replacement for QEMU in the scsi disk info
SCSI_REPLACER='<WOOT>'

# what to use as a replacement for QEMU in the atapi disk info
ATAPI_REPLACER='<WOOT>'

# what to use as a replacement for QEMU in the microdrive info
MICRODRIVE_REPLACER='<WOOT>'

# what to use as a replacement for QEMU in bochs in drive info
BOCHS_BLOCK_REPLACER='<WOOT>'
BOCHS_BLOCK_REPLACER2='<WOOT>'
BOCHS_BLOCK_REPLACER3='<WOOT>'

# what to use as a replacement for BXPC in bochs in ACPI info
BXPC_REPLACER='<WOOT>'

Any help would be appreciated.
Tried searching through ACPIDUMP as the instructions told me to, but could not find the Hardware IDs needed to replace the  occurances.
